CMake escape ";" in list item when converting list to string
Lets define the following CMake List:
set(options
  "-DVERSION=\\\"42\\\""
  "-DADDITIONAL_VERSIONS=\"MODULE_INFO(my_module, \\\"42.0\\\")\\;\"")

I need to transform the options list into a string that is passed to the C compiler looking like this:
"-DVERSION=\"42\" -DADDITIONAL_VERSIONS="MODULE_INFO(my_module, \"42.0");""

I've managed to get everything correct, but the ";" after module info is skipped no matter what I try:

string(REPLACE ";" " " options_text "${options}")
string(REGEX REPLACE "([^\\]);" "\\1 <replaced>" options_text "${options}")
string(JOIN " " options_text "${options}")
foreach over the list, checking for empty items and replacing them...

Ultimately, I must be able to handle any valid and properly escaped C Preprocessor define.
Thank you in advance for your ideas.

OK I can answer my own question:
This call was part of a CMake function body that was previously processed by cmake_parse_arguments which seemed to have chopped off the ;.
using the new cmake_parse_arguments(PARSE_ARGV ...) function solved the problem as documented in cmake_parse_arguments
